# Which delimiter to use when loading CSV data into Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I've come across a problem with loading some CSV files into my Postgres tables. I have data that looks like this:

```
ID,IS_ALIVE,BODY_TEXT
123,true,Hi Joe, I am looking for a new vehicle, can you help me out?
```

Now, the problem here is that the text in what is supposed to be the `BODY_TEXT` column is unstructured email data and can contain any sort of characters, and when I run the following `COPY` command it's failing because there are multiple `,` characters within the `BODY_TEXT`.

```
COPY sent from ('my_file.csv') DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

How can I resolve this so that everything in the `BODY_TEXT` column gets loaded as-is without the load command potentially using characters within it as separators?

Comment: The problem isn't with the load command - it's with the file. CSV doesn't allow commas inside a field (it just breaks up the value to two fields) unless it's protected by quotes (`"`s).

Comment: You should produce the CSV with another delimiter value

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the fixing the source file format you can do it by PostgreSQL itself.

Load all lines from file to temporary table:

```
create temporary table t (x text);
copy t from 'foo.csv';
```

Then you can to split each string using regexp like:

```
select regexp_matches(x, '^([0-9]+),(true|false),(.*)$') from t;

                              regexp_matches                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {123,true,"Hi Joe, I am looking for a new vehicle, can you help me out?"}
 {456,false,"Hello, honey, there is what I want to ask you."}
(2 rows)
```

You can use this query to load data to your destination table:

```
insert into sent(id, is_alive, body_text)
  select x[1], x[2], x[3] 
  from (
    select regexp_matches(x, '^([0-9]+),(true|false),(.*)$') as x 
    from t) t
```